# Is "falcon" an adverb in the phrase "Falcon...PUNCH!"?

Tags: adverbs

This is from Super Smash Bros: https://supersmashbros.fandom.com/wiki/Falcon_Punch.  We had a discussion at work. Some people think "falcon" is the adverb to "punch". Some people think "falcon punch" is a verb on its own.

Comment: It's not clear from your description what the grammatical function of the phrase is. Are you giving an instruction to perform a move, or are you shouting out the name of a move as you're doing it, possibly imagining you're a commentator describing the action?

Comment: The linked site give "Falcon Punch" only as a noun.

Comment: You should really include examples in your question. Linked pages change over time and can not be relied on.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely *falcon* is an attributive noun modifying the noun *punch*.

We probably can't know without knowing the speaker's intentions.  Does he mean "[Now I'm going to] falcon punch," or does he mean "[This move is called a] falcon punch"?

My assumption is that it's the latter.  This is based on the similarity of this utterance to phrases that are less likely to contain verbs.  For example, in the same game, the character Ness says, "PK fire."  *Fire* can also be a verb or a noun, but we don't say, "I'm going to bullet fire" or "I'm going to arrow fire," so it seems more likely that he's naming a kind of fire (a PK fire) rather than saying, "I'm going to fire PK."

And these utterances follow a tradition that goes back (at least) to Street Fighter 2, where we hear the character Dhalsim say, "yoga fire" as he launches a fireball, rather than a yoga ball.